# Error 500 on new apache virtual host

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've created a new virtual host on apache and enabled the site.
It looks as follows

```
    # Place any notes or comments you have here
# It will make any customisation easier to understand in the weeks to come

# domain: domain1.com
# public: /home/demo/public_html/domain1.com/

<VirtualHost *:80>

  # Admin email, Server Name (domain name) and any aliases
  ServerAdmin webmaster@domain1.com
  ServerName  elexy.com
  ServerAlias www.elexy.com


  # Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
  DirectoryIndex index.html
  DocumentRoot /var/www/elexy/


  # Custom log file locations
  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error-elexy.com.log
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access-elexy.com.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

When i vist http://localhost/elexy/
I get an internal server error 500.

From the log, i get

> Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable
>   configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the
>   limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

I have an .htaccess file in the folder, however, if i copy this directory to /var/www/html/ and try to access it. It works just fine.

I'm not sure what i'm missing here.

Here's the .htaccess file
Now this is a software that someone else wrote in php. I did not write the .htaccess myself.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews +Indexes
<FilesMatch "\.(htaccess|htpasswd|ini|log|sh|inc|bak|tpl)$">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

# Cache Control
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|css|js)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteOptions MaxRedirects=1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [L]

# Installer
RewriteRule ^install/?$ install.php [L]

# Static Pages
RewriteRule ^static/([^/]+)/?$ static.php?url=$1 [L]

# Contacts
RewriteRule ^contacts/?$ contact.php [L]

# Directory
RewriteRule ^directory/?$ directory.php [L]
RewriteRule ^directory/([^/]+)/?$ directory.php?view=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^directory/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ directory.php?view=$1&page=$2 [L]

# Search
RewriteRule ^search/?$ search.php [L]
RewriteRule ^search/hashtag/([^/]+)/?$ search.php?query=$1&hashtag=1 [L]
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)/?$ search.php?query=$1&hashtag=0 [L]

# Sign(in|up|out)
RewriteRule ^signin/?$ sign.php?do=in [L]
RewriteRule ^signup/?$ sign.php?do=up [L]
RewriteRule ^signout/?$ sign.php?do=out [L]
RewriteRule ^reset/?$ sign.php?do=reset [L]
RewriteRule ^activation/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ activation.php?id=$1&token=$2 [L]

# Social Logins
RewriteRule ^connect/([^/]+)/?$ connect.php?do=connect&provider=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^revoke/([^/]+)/?$ connect.php?do=revoke&provider=$1 [L]

# Packages
RewriteRule ^packages/?$ packages.php [L]

# Started
RewriteRule ^started/?$ started.php [L]
RewriteRule ^started/finished?$ started.php?finished=true [L]

# Messages
RewriteRule ^messages/?$ messages.php [L]
RewriteRule ^messages/new?$ messages.php?view=new [L]
RewriteRule ^messages/([^/]+)/?$ messages.php?cid=$1 [L]

# Notifications
RewriteRule ^notifications/?$ notifications.php [L]

# Settings
RewriteRule ^settings/?$ settings.php [L]
RewriteRule ^settings/([^/]+)/?$ settings.php?view=$1 [L]

# Posts & Photos
RewriteRule ^posts/([^/]+)/?$ post.php?post_id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^photos/([^/]+)/?$ photo.php?photo_id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^buy/([^/]+)/?$ buy.php?post_id=$1 [L]

# Saved
RewriteRule ^saved/?$ index.php?view=saved [L]

# People
RewriteRule ^people/?$ people.php [L]
RewriteRule ^people/find/?$ people.php?view=find [L]
RewriteRule ^people/friend_requests/?$ people.php?view=friend_requests [L]
RewriteRule ^people/sent_requests/?$ people.php?view=sent_requests [L]

# Pages
RewriteRule ^pages/?$ pages.php [L]
RewriteRule ^pages/liked/?$ pages.php?view=liked [L]
RewriteRule ^pages/manage/?$ pages.php?view=manage [L]
RewriteRule ^pages/([^/]+)/?$ page.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^pages/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ page.php?username=$1&view=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^pages/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ page.php?username=$1&view=$2&id=$3 [L]

# Groups
RewriteRule ^groups/?$ groups.php [L]
RewriteRule ^groups/joined/?$ groups.php?view=joined [L]
RewriteRule ^groups/manage/?$ groups.php?view=manage [L]
RewriteRule ^groups/([^/]+)/?$ group.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^groups/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ group.php?username=$1&view=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^groups/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ group.php?username=$1&view=$2&id=$3 [L]

# Events
RewriteRule ^events/?$ events.php [L]
RewriteRule ^events/going/?$ events.php?view=going [L]
RewriteRule ^events/interested/?$ events.php?view=interested [L]
RewriteRule ^events/invited/?$ events.php?view=invited [L]
RewriteRule ^events/manage/?$ events.php?view=manage [L]
RewriteRule ^events/([^/]+)/?$ event.php?event_id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^events/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ event.php?event_id=$1&view=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^events/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ event.php?event_id=$1&view=$2&id=$3 [L]

# Blogs
RewriteRule ^articles/?$ index.php?view=articles [L]
RewriteRule ^blogs/?$ blogs.php [L]
RewriteRule ^blogs/new/?$ blogs.php?view=new [L]
RewriteRule ^blogs/edit/([^/]+)/?$ blogs.php?view=edit&post_id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^blogs/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ blogs.php?view=article&post_id=$1 [L]

# Market
RewriteRule ^products/?$ index.php?view=products [L]
RewriteRule ^market/?$ market.php [L]
RewriteRule ^market/search/?$ market.php?view=search [L]
RewriteRule ^market/search/([^/]+)/?$ market.php?view=search&query=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^market/search/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ market.php?view=search&query=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^market/category/([^/]+)/?$ market.php?view=category&category_id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^market/category/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ market.php?view=category&category_id=$1&category_url=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^market/category/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ market.php?view=category&category_id=$1&category_url=$2&page=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^market/([^/]+)/?$ market.php?page=$1 [L]

# Games
RewriteRule ^games/?$ games.php [L]
RewriteRule ^games/played/?$ games.php?view=played [L]
RewriteRule ^games/([^/]+)/?$ game.php?id=$1 [L]

#Movies
RewriteRule ^movies/?$ movies.php?view=all [L]
RewriteRule ^movies/movies/?$ movies.php?view=movies [L]
RewriteRule ^movies/tv/?$ movies.php?view=tv [L]
RewriteRule ^movies/([^/]+)/?$ movie.php?id=$1 [L]

#Comics
RewriteRule ^comics/?$ comics.php [L]
RewriteRule ^comics/add/?$ comics.php?view=add [L]
RewriteRule ^comics/([^/]+)/?$ comic.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^comics/edit/([^/]+)/?$ comics.php?view=edit&comic_id=$1 [L]

# Admin Panel
RewriteRule ^admincp/?$ admin.php [L]
RewriteRule ^admincp/([^/]+)/?$ admin.php?view=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^admincp/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ admin.php?view=$1&sub_view=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^admincp/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ admin.php?view=$1&sub_view=$2&id=$3 [L]

# Profile
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ profile.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ profile.php?username=$1&view=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ profile.php?username=$1&view=$2&id=$3 [L]
```

Im not exactly sure of what's going on here.
Looking for suggestions from people that knows what they're doing better than i am.

Thanks.

Comment: If you set up a virtualhost with the servername "elexy.com", why are you going to "localhost/elexy"?

Comment: @rickdenhaan Sorry, im quite new to configuring apache, i was just following a tutorial and i figured it wouldn't matter if the domain wasn't configured.

Comment: Your configuration is telling Apache: "for any incoming requests with the hostname elexy.com (ServerName) or www.elexy.com (ServerAlias), serve the files in /var/www/elexy (DocumentRoot)". If you're accessing "localhost/elexy", the hostname is "localhost" and not "elexy.com" so this config file doesn't apply and your computer is loading the default site (which by default tries to serve whatever's in /var/www/html).

Comment: @rickdenhaan so i can either add elexy.com to point to my localhost in the hosts file or change server alias to my local ip address?

Comment: The first one, yeah. Although that will ensure you never end up on the actual domain name. Personally, I usually set up a different hostname like "elexy.local" to point to localhost so that elexy.com would still point to the production site.

Comment: @rickdenhaan Sweet, it works. But im wondering how i would go about achieving the same thing without having a domain name. Just to access it with the localhost alias.

Comment: With that many rewriterules in your htaccess, subfolders or aliases are going to be some trouble. You'll probably be able to just use localhost if you drop the files in /var/www/html, but if you have multiple projects on the same machine that's more trouble than it's worth IMHO.